# How do I use this query in vb.net - I cannot get my head around converting from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select * FROM Win32_Battery");

foreach (ManagementObject o in new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get())
{
    uint level = (uint)o.Properties["EstimatedChargeRemaining"].Value;
}
```

Simple in c# - really cannot get my head around it in vb.net -> tried online and manual conversion and keep getting stuck

`For Each o As ManagementObject In New ManagementObjectSearcher(query2)` <- getting stuck at this point I think -> not sure how to do the `.get`

If anyone can help me convert that would be wonderful - preferably the full conversion as I have found parts of my answer all over and they all seem to 'miss a step'

Comment: The trick is that you can put everything om the righthand side of a `foreach` statement that returns an `IEnumerable`. How you get that is your choice.

Comment: Are you sure that this is your C# code? There is no direct cast from object to uint, so the 'level' initialization throws an exception. I needed to use System.Convert.ToUInt32 to get this to run. (The VB equivalent specified by others *does* run fine).

Comment: no the above code does run fine - fixed the problem -> was down to the second battery not being installed correctly -> in c# this just cast to 0 but for some reason in vb.net it threw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much exactly as you'd expect:

```
Dim query As New ObjectQuery("Select * FROM Win32_Battery")

For Each o As ManagementObject In New ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get()
    Dim level = CUInt(o.Properties("EstimatedChargeRemaining").Value)
Next
```

Comment: hmmm that is what I have been trying but it gives me an empty for each

Comment: So, are you saying that when you execute that VB code, Get returns an empty list while the original C# produces a non-empty list on the same machine?

Comment: I just tried that VB code on my laptop and Get returned a collection with one item in it, as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks - it was indeed the correct code - weird fault with battery was throwing an error -> c# just cast to 0 -> vb just cried and died but with no info as to why!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=135f6af9-71e5-4043-8e14-ad9e67650d38) site to covert your code. The following code has converted from developer fusion.

```
Dim query As New ObjectQuery("Select * FROM Win32_Battery")

For Each o As ManagementObject In New ManagementObjectSearcher(query).[Get]()
    Dim level As UInteger = CUInt(o.Properties("EstimatedChargeRemaining").Value)
Next
```

Comment: also tried this with empty for each - will have another look!